# Things to do during a five-hour layover in Athens, Greece?

Tags: layovers, greece, activities, athens

I'm going to be in the Athens airport for five and a half hours.  I know the city is quite a distance away.  Is there anything of interest nearby that I could do to alleviate the boredom?

Comment: Shipping. Not really, there is not much to doin ATH apart airplane spotting and checking/preparing/uploading your holiday photos.

Comment: What do you like doing?

Comment: The city is about an hour away by bus, or half an hour by taxi, so it depends how long you think you will be at customs, baggage collection, where you are going/coming from etc. to how much time you have, you might be able to fully do one main tourist attraction. There's plenty of beaches/ocean view points a 25 minute taxi ride in the opposite direction, which you could go to and relax for a while

Comment: Google Maps says you can reach the Acropolis in 40 minutes with a taxi, so provided you don’t have to worry about bags, check-in or inbound passport control (I understand you are arriving from Corfu) and want to be back at the airport one hour early, that leaves you over 2 hours on site with quite some margin. But given you asked the question 4 hours ago that may be a bit too late

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much to do nearby the airport, in terms of tourist attractions, and given your short time frame, I would probably stay put. Rushing to the Acropolis is just not worth it, as the lines are long to enter and you could spend days there just soaking in all the history and walking around.

According [to this article](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/layovers/things-to-do-on-layover-athens-airport.htm), there are 8 things to do on a layover at Athens Airport:

> ### 1. Eat
>
> No matter what time you arrive, you can grab a bite to eat, as several restaurants are open 24-hours. Stop at one of
>   the Greek options, including the Kir-Yanni Wine Bar, or head to any of
>   the several European cafes and sit-down restaurants. Of course, you’re
>   never far from a McDonald’s or Starbucks either. A grocery store is
>   located pre-Security, so venture there if you need to pick up any
>   snacks for the next leg of your journey.
>
> ### 2. Hang out in a lounge
>
> Airport lounges are no longer for fancy flyers only! No matter what class you’re flying, you can
>   head to an airport lounge and enjoy good food and drinks, hop on WiFi,
>   and catch up on the news all in a quieter environment than the main
>   terminal. There are several lounges that welcome any travellers
>   regardless of airline or class of service – simply buy a pass online
>   or use your membership in a lounge program to gain entry. See our
>   Athens Airport Guide for locations and amenities.
>
> ### 3. Get a dose of history
>
> For many travellers, Greece is synonymous with history. Even if you’re only in the country for a layover, you
>   can still take in some ancient and more recent past. The Main Terminal
>   features permanent exhibitions from the Acropolis Museum in town.
>   There’s also the Exhibition of Archaeological Findings and the
>   Eleftherios Venizelos Permanent Exhibition is dedicated to Greek
>   aviation history. Open daily from 6am – 11pm.
>
> ### 4. Go exploring
>
> Beyond the airport Layover SightseeingIf you’ve got a few hours, you can take advantage of the airport’s location to get
>   out and about for some fresh air and local culture.
>
> Layover under 5 hours The airport’s location means you’re within easy
>   range of a couple attractions, and sometimes you need to just get out
>   and breathe fresh air, even if it’s only for a couple hours. Tour a
>   vineyard and sample the wines at nearby wineries like Gikas Winery,
>   Domaine Papagiannakos, and Eklektikon – they may even provide airport
>   pick-up. If you’ve got the kids in tow, take a 10-minute taxi ride to
>   the Attica Park Zoo. If you’d rather shop, international superstore
>   IKEA is located a few minutes away by bus or taxi, or pop over to the
>   McArthurGlen Designer Outlets, a quick 15-minute taxi ride.
>
> Layovers longer than 5 hours The Athens metro system can have you in
>   the heart of Athens in about 45-60 minutes, so you’ll want a few hours
>   to head into the city. Take a traditional walking tour by getting off
>   at the Acropolis metro station; stroll along Dionysiou Areopagitou
>   Street, a pedestrian road that leads to the Acropolis and accompanying
>   museum. Or pop off the metro at the Monastiraki stop, and wind your
>   way through traditional neighborhoods with white homes, cafes, and
>   low-key Greek restaurants.
>
> ### 5. Shop
>
> A layover is often the perfect opportunity to shop at your leisure, and this airport has plenty of options. The Hellenic
>   Duty Free has all your standard necessities, and other shops
>   specialize in cigars, jewelry, perfume, and sunglasses. If you really
>   want to splurge or put give your credit card a workout, check out
>   high-end boutiques like Michael Kors, Salvatore Ferragamo, and Max
>   Mara.
>
> ### 6. Spa Massage
>
> If you’re in need of some pampering, the spa inside the Sofitel hotel is open to non-guests. Services include facials,
>   massages, manicures and pedicures, and more. Note that the Sofitel is
>   located just opposite the airport terminal, so you’ll have to exit and
>   re-enter Security.
>
> ### 7. Get online
>
> Stay connected to friends and family, update your social media accounts or surf the internet courtesy of the airport’s
>   free WiFi.  You’ll want to use your time wisely though, as there is
>   currently a 45 minute time limit restriction. Boo!
>
> Uninterrupted, premium options are available for a cost.
>
> ### 8. Sleep
>
> When it’s time to catch up on some Z’s, there are plenty of stiff seats and benches. Travellers try to camp out
>   overnight, but the airport isn’t always friendly to them – sometimes
>   playing loud announcements or waking up anyone who’s dozing. For
>   better quality sleep, you’ll have to shell out some cash – a Sofitel
>   is located just opposite the main terminal, with day rooms available
>   from 12pm – 6pm. Several other hotels are located within a few
>   minutes’ drive, with some providing free airport shuttle service. For
>   details on locations, shuttles, and day rooms, see our Athens Airport
>   Guide.

They also include an [Athens Airport Guide](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/athens-airport-guide.htm) for more information about more services and facilities available, such as food, WiFi, mobile charging, luggage storage, nearby airport hotels, and much more

[image: Temple of Poseidon]

And if you really want to leave the airport to go sightseeing, I would suggest avoiding Athens altogether and going to Sounion, which is about 45 minutes/46 km away, to see the Temple of Poseidon, where according to the myth, this is the site where Aegeus, king of Athens, fell into the sea because of a misunderstanding. This is where the Aegean sea earned its name for centuries to come.

Comment: "If you’d rather shop, international superstore IKEA is located a few minutes away". Oh yes, most definitely, I'm in transit between two flights, I'll go buy some furniture at IKEA :-) That's weird advice...

Comment: @jcaron IKEA also sells smaller items.

Comment: You can buy traditional Greek 'Sweedish meatballs' in IKEA